# Accepting incoming call using Conversation Control in 1:1 conversation

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

How do i accept an incoming call in a 1:1 conversation when im using the Conversation Control?

At the moment im only able to accept a call in a group conversation.

In a 1:1 conversation i dont get notified whenever i get an incoming call.

Ive tried to get it to work on my own web app and on the samples published by Microsoft but i'm facing the same issue on both of them.

1:1 audio calls work fine when the calls gets accepted with the Skype for business Client.

Answer (score 0):

A work around is just not using a 1:1 conversation.

So: Create a new empty conversation, then add a new participant to the conversation.

DONT create a conversation with a participant already in it. Add all participant afterwards.